# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml' and AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'load'?

Tags: python, pip, yaml, homebrew

I have a script that does `import yaml` and then uses `yaml.load` and `yaml.Loader`

I previously installed yaml months ago using `pip3 install yaml`, and that worked for another script

Now, running another script was saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'` again (but ipython works when doing `import yaml` as well as `from yaml import load`). Tried installing using brew but now I get a new error `AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'load'.`

Why is this? And how can I fix whatever's going on? I don't have any files named 'yaml' at my script level

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+yaml

Answer (score -2):

`python3 -m pip install pyyaml` worked. I should rly learn pip/installing